# From where Eclipse CDT takes paths in Makefile project?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

my project must be "not CDT project". I'm building it by Makefile from command line, and its build correctly. But whole project in Eclipse in many places have unresolved errors. Not all statements are unresolved. It's looks randomly on first shoot (but its not).

I'm don't know where to add paths (I knows path to unresolved files). Problem is because "not CDT" are unabled to be changed from Project/Properties.

How "not CDT" project can be configured?

Comment: @haccks Since the OP didn't ask for any external tool, but explicitly tagged [tag:eclipse]-[tag:cdt] and asks for the necessary configurations for eclipse. So why Off-Topic??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `Project->Properties->C++ General->Path and Symbols` and set your include path's there. Rerun the indexer on the project afterwards.

Such a project is called a 'Makefile' project BTW, of course it's still a CDT project!

Comment: I try do it earlier but in Path and Symbols I see only one message: "This project is not a CDT project."

Comment: @Adreasx How did you import your c++/c code into the project?